# Japanese Directors and films

Tags: film, directors, foreign

I'm doing a dissertation on my film course on Japanese Auteurs and how they compare to Western Auteurs in their approach to film. If anyone could suggest any Japanese film directors that they really like then that would be great. Film suggestions are also welcome.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I really like Kyoshi Kurosawa's work. His style is very spartan and almost lo fi, sonically. Two films to check out are Pulse and Cure (Tokyo Sonata is another). Dead silence is used at certain points in these films, and the effect it has in each case is interesting.

His films can be difficult to watch if you're not in the right mood, but his style is pretty unique IMHO.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Kaneto Shindo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaneto_Shindo), especially *Onibaba*. Kurasawa, I like *[The Bad Sleep Well](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0054460/?ref_=nm_flmg_dr_12)* a lot, Ozu, Naruse. I also really rate Tomu Uchida, if you can get a copy you must watch *[Killing in Yoshiwara](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0187119/)*.

+1 for Kyoshi Kurosawa too.

I've been meaning to get round to watching more of Kinji Fukasaku's films (of *Battle Royale* fame), so maybe that's a good idea too.